# How to change the Scrollbars Arrow Keys in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Using the following code to set the style for vertical Qscrollbar. It gives the appearance/result as attached photo. I want to change the up and down arrow from Square to the actual up arrow ( triangle) on top and the down arrow at the bottom(inverse triangle). How to obtain it?

[image]

```
   QScrollBar:vertical {
   background: rgb(220,220,220);
   width: 15px;
   margin: 22px 0 22px 0; }

   QScrollBar::handle:vertical {
   background: rgb(169,169,169);
   min-height: 10px; }
   
   QScrollBar::add-line:vertical {
   border: 0px solid grey;
   background: rgb(220,220,220);
   height: 20px;
   subcontrol-position: bottom;
   subcontrol-origin: margin; }

   QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {
   border: 0px solid red;
   background: rgb(220,220,220);
   height: 20px;
   subcontrol-position: top;
   subcontrol-origin: margin;}
   
   QScrollBar::up-arrow:vertical, QScrollBar::down-arrow:vertical {
   border: 0px solid red;
   display: &#5123;
   width: 5px;
   height: 5px;
   background:black;}
```

Comment: Short answer: you can't. Setting a stylesheet on complex widgets like scroll bars requires a *complete* setting of stylesheet parameters, including arrow *buttons* (not "keys"). If you want to customize the look of a QScrollBar using stylesheets, you need to use custom images (as explained in [the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qscrollbar)). The reason is that using stylesheets on such widgets completely change their look (and partially, behavior to mouse events), so you cannot rely on the current style drawing anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use images to get arrow icons.

```css
QScrollBar::right-arrow,
QScrollBar::left-arrow,
QScrollBar::up-arrow,
QScrollBar::down-arrow {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    background: black;
}

QScrollBar::right-arrow {
    image: url("://icons/theme-dark/caret_right.svg");
}
QScrollBar::left-arrow {
    image: url("://icons/theme-dark/caret_left.svg");
}
QScrollBar::up-arrow {
    image: url("://icons/theme-dark/caret_up.svg");
}
QScrollBar::down-arrow {
    image: url("://icons/theme-dark/caret_down.svg");
}
```

The images can be anything, in any format Qt supports (png, jpg, gif, etc). The above URL syntax uses images embedded in an included Qt resource file (but they could also be `file://` URLs, or actual network requests (http/s, etc)).

You do not need the `:vertical` or `:horizontal` qualifiers (the elements are already "directional").  Also the way you're using `display` is incorrect, and besides Qt doesn't support it anyway (nor `content` which is I think what you meant).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to manually supplying images for arrows, you could try different window styles. If you use Designer for your app, you can preview styles from Form...Preview In -> Style. It's hard to find in the docs, but if you [look here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/gallery.html), there are some styles.

In your code you do it at the app level:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create('fusion'))
```

Comment: To know the available styles, add `print(QStyleFactory.keys())`